# Bootstrap button positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've this Bootstrap HTML markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="field col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Large button</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">X</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I would like the *large button* to fill the column (col-md-6), therefore I've used `btn-block`. But I would like the X button to float right in the same line, taking a bit of the width of the *Large button*.

The *X button* should stay small, and the *Large button* should fill up the rest of the width.

How can I do that?

See [my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dennismadsen/oayw7uhh/).

Comment: Well, `btn-block` gives the button a `width:100%` and `display:block` so it is not going to let you do that (unless you are ok with overwriting it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use input groups to keep everything together.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

> Extend form controls by adding text or buttons before, after, or on
>   both sides of any text-based . Use .input-group with an
>   .input-group-addon to prepend or append elements to a single
>   .form-control.
>
> Buttons in input groups are a bit different and require one extra
>   level of nesting. Instead of .input-group-addon, you'll need to use
>   .input-group-btn to wrap the buttons. This is required due to default
>   browser styles that cannot be overridden.

Here is the modification I made to your fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/oayw7uhh/5/

All you need to do is surround both elements with a input-group-div

Then, wrap the X button in a span with the class input-group-btn.

https://jsfiddle.net/dennismadsen/oayw7uhh/

Your finished code is

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="field col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Large button</button>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">X</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about margin between the buttons?

Comment: If you add padding to the input-group-btn element, you can separate the two buttons.